# How to delete multiple selected items from array at once in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, indexof

I am working on a to-do list application. one feature i am trying to add is clearing selected items that would delete items from an array that are checked off in a check box.

i am running an event listener that when the "clear selected" button is clicked, it would run a function that deletes the items selected from the array.

i am attempting this with the following code:

```
clearSelect.addEventListener("click", function() {
if (checkBox.checked == true) {
  liAdd.remove();
  removeSelectedItems(userInput);
  function removeSelectedItems(selected) {
    let selectedItems = toDoArray.indexOf(selected);
    toDoArray.splice(selectedItems, 1);
    console.log(toDoArray);
  }
}
saveToLocalStorage(); });
```

at first it works ok, if i enter in 10 items, then select and delete 3-4 at once - the index of the items match their position in the array and they delete fine. however, if i then select 3-4 more and delete again, the indices of the array items are all screwy, popping up as -1 and 0. and then i'll weirdly end up with an empty array after refreshing. i tried adding an `if (selected != -1)` to stop the array items to show as -1 index # but that did not work.

any help is apprecaited, thanks!

Comment: are you familiar with `Array.filter()`? You can use that to create a new array, simply filtering out the ones that match a given criteria. No need to worry about indexes or whatever, it's simply populating and returning a completely new array. The problem here is, you're trying to mutate an array while you're using it as the basis for mutation - much like trying to cut off a tree limb while standing on it.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use something like the Array `filter` method? You could use that in conjunction with a `Set` object.

You can do it by array element or by index.

```js
const myArr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

// By element
const toRemove = new Set(['a', 'c', 'e']);
const filtered = myArr.filter(el => !toRemove.has(el));
console.log(filtered);

// By index
const toRemoveIndex = new Set([0, 2, 4]);
const filteredByIndex = myArr.filter((_, i) => !toRemoveIndex.has(i));

console.log(filteredByIndex);
```